# Stop thread and save map to disk when JVM terminates

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I have a Java class that starts a thread like this. This thread must be started in a `static {}` section.

```
private static final Thread thCleaner = new Thread(new SessionCleaner(mapSession));
static { thCleaner.start(); }
```

When JVM terminates, I need to stop this thread and save to disk the elements of a `ConcurrentMap`.

> Code added from user's own comments:

```
private void writeMap() { 
   ObjectOutputStream oos = null; 
   try { 
       oos = new   ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mapFilePath));
       oos.writeObject(this.mapSession); 
   } 
   catch (Exception e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
   finally { if (oos != null) { try { oos.close(); } catch (Exception e) {} } }
```

}

I tried a `shutdownHook`, but I could not load `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` to write the map (because JVM is terminating)because it's throws this exception:

```
28-ene-2014 13:56:00 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass INFO: Acceso ilegal: esta instancia de aplicaciÃ³n web ya ha sido parada. 
Could not load java.io.ObjectOutputStream. java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:15‌​66) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295) 
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:627) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) 
at com.vpfw.tests.skiart.SkiArtDispatchInterruption$1.run
```

And a finalizer is not working (and it's not recommended). What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Somehow signal the JVM before you shut it down.

Comment: Couldn't load ObjectOutputStream? You mean the class? If that's the only problem, just use it before the shutdownhook so it's already loaded. In any case, shutdownhook is the way to go.

Comment: The shutdown hook interruopts the thread. That works. But inside this thread, when it's interrupted, I have to save to disk a map. It's when ObjectInputStream is not available.

Comment: @JBalaguero Can you post the exception you get when trying to save the map?

Comment: Yes whats the exact problem? Class not found or something else? Because the reason is unclear.

Comment: 28-ene-2014 13:56:00 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Acceso ilegal: esta instancia de aplicaciÃ³n web ya ha sido parada.  Could not load java.io.ObjectOutputStream.  java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:627)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at com.vpfw.tests.skiart.SkiArtDispatchInterruption$1.run

Comment: when thread is interrupted, I call this methos:

Comment: private void writeMap()
 {
  ObjectOutputStream oos = null;  
  
  try
  {
   oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mapFilePath));
   oos.writeObject(this.mapSession);
  }
  catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  finally
  {
   if (oos != null) 
   {
 try { oos.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}  
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Since your app is running on Tomcat, it's not possible to save this data using ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()?

Answer (score 1):

The Exception is thrown, because the ClassLoader tries to load a new class during termination of the JVM. A possible solution is to run the whole saving chain at least once during execution to ensure that all classes are loaded.

In general it is not a good idea to react to JVM shutdown, as for once not all functionalities are still available, and for second no one can guarantee that the JVM is actually shut down properly. Under certain circumstances (e.g. Linux kill command) a JVM can instantly terminate without granting time to perform saves. If you want to make sure that data is available on restart, you need to frequently do saves in between and - if possible - have some form of rolling save-file, should the JVM terminate during write.